# Android Studio 1.0 - When trying to start app or debug, Error: Default Activity not found

Tags: android-studio

New to the Android-Studio. I created an app and built with no errors; tried to run it and get the title error

[image: Vers]

(IDE gives no hint as to how to fix it):

[image: look at the bottom of dialog]